# Login and Registration link disappear from mvc5 application menu bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am new to mvc5, and following a tutorial. When I start adding role to newly register user in Register action of AccountController, the link for login and registration are disappeared from menu bar. I undo the changes but links do not appeared back.

Comment: please provide us with code what you have tried?

Comment: The code I added for registration, I comment it. It did not add any extra code. It is just a application with individual authentication application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") has been remove from _Layout.cshtml file. I have added this piece of code in _Layout.cshtml file, and link to login and registration appear again in menu bar.